# Problem In Creating Genesis Block Twister-Core using Ubuntu and (Qt Creator IDE)

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, genesis-block, altcoin-development

I am trying to create a genesis block in twister-core using Ubuntu and IDE Qt Creator. I have compiled the twister-core successfully, I have changed the these parameters for creating the genesis block `pszTimestamp`, `genesis.nTime`   and  `genesis.nNonce`. Then I re-compiled it successfully. When I am executing `twisterd` in the terminal using this command

```
./twisterd -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=pwd -rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
```

this error occured:

> Terminal Error :
>   Assertion `hashGenesisBlock == uint256("b24b7a9c568b4ae288c0be34699c4c79fc22848e7c346afd5f63901e41ed8640")' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

When I run it On Qt-Creator same error occur Error:

> twisterd: ../twister/src/chainparams.cpp:216: CMainParams::CMainParams(): Assertion `hashGenesisBlock == uint256("b24b7a9c568b4ae288c0be34699c4c79fc22848e7c346afd5f63901e41ed8640")' failed.
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   ../twister-qt-Output/twisterd exited with code 0

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a new Genesis Block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/21303/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chainparams.cpp` contains a line of code that checks whether the chain’s genesis block is equal to a specified hash. Since you created a new genesis block, you will have to update the value to your own hash.

You can see an example for the line here:

```
 hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
 assert(hashGenesisBlock == uint256("9915158279673d101912be80f25c20627f1dd8bf5231e7c46bfec5ed19737f44"));
```

Which I took from [miguelfreitas/twister-core/…/chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/miguelfreitas/twister-core/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L216)

To figure out what to put there, you can print `genesis.GetHash()` and replace the old hash in the assertion.

To print it the hash of the genesis block, you can use

```
printf("genesis.GetHash = %s\n", genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
```

just above the line with the assertion, which will write to the `~/.bitcoin/debug.log`.

Comment: Hi , I ave also printed the genesis.hashMerkleRoot using above example ,Please tell me where I put these hash to create genesis block?

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=391983.msg4223449#msg4223449

Comment: at newest source bitcoin 0.15.1, debug.log file does not be generated? Why?

Comment: @leegod: If you have a new question, please start another topic

Comment: Hi. So even if after change hash value to match, but still another occured, 

ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)

I posted this forum, replier says 

"Your genesis block is wrong. You actually have to mine the block, not just change the parameters."

but, how to? I searched a lot but most code mine the block is outdated, and not work at currently. Do you know this solution? Thanks.