# CPU Miner return Internal Server Error for getblocktemplate request

Tags: json-rpc, altcoin, miner-configuration, getblocktemplate

I was developing an altcoin using bitcoin v 0.17. I am using CPU miner for mining purposes.
I started the miner using this command:

```
./minerd -a sha256d -o http://localhost:19230 -O adreno:adreno@123 --coinbase-addr=2NDMNtJB4wR2mEkDpFiqSr7yzuYAzT7dpDZ -D --protocol-dump
```

I got this response

```
[2018-10-30 22:18:47] JSON protocol request:
{"method": "getblocktemplate", "params": [{"capabilities": ["coinbasetxn", "coinbasevalue", "longpoll", "workid"], "rules": ["segwit"]}], "id":0}


* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:19230/
[2018-10-30 22:18:47] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 19230 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'adreno'
> POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:19230
Authorization: Basic YWRyZW5vOmFkcmVub0AxMjM=
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 147
User-Agent: cpuminer/2.5.0
X-Mining-Extensions: midstate

* The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
[2018-10-30 22:18:47] HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

When I directly hit the RPC server with a `getblocktemplate` request, I get this response

```
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-10,"message":"Adreno is downloading blocks..."},"id":"1"}
```

Comment: This is a good start for your answer, but could you please add a phrase or two to explain what your question is, or what you're asking for help with?

Comment: I can't able to generate genesis block

Comment: There are a number of questions about creating a genesis block for a new altcoin: E.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/21303/5406. Try checking the tags [tag:altcoin-development] and [tag:genesis-block]. Please update your question here to more clearly specify your question.

Comment: I have tried the solution `gen=1` and other CPU miner suggested in other Stackoverflow link. But it does not work .